# Any earth-based film or color still photography of Apollo CM re-entries?

Tags: apollo-program, history, photography

After watching the IMAX Apollo 11 film today I wondered if there was any film footage from outside of an Apollo Command Module (CM) re-entry (or even color stills).  It does not have to be from 11.

The problem was probably the splashdown point being in the Pacific.

I've seen some black-and-white stills of Apollo 13 re-entry, and re-entry film footage shot from inside some of the CMs (some of this was in the film) but not externally taken footage or color pictures.  I suspect that the people that assembled this film would have used it if it existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least [stills from Apollo 8:](https://www.space.com/19250-apollo-8-reentry.html)

[image]

> In this historic photo from the U.S. space agency, a reentry photograph of Apollo 8 which was taken by a U.S. Air Force ALOTS (Airborne Lightweight Optical Tracking System) camera mounted on a KC-135A aircraft flown at 40,000 ft altitude. Apollo 8 splashed down at 10:15 a.m., Dec. 27, 1968, in the central Pacific approximately 1,000 miles South-Southwest of Hawaii.

The reentry phase was nicely visible, but [a long way away](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12745/re-entry-dynamics) from the splashdown point.

[image]

Assuming the end of blackout is also the point where the capsule no longer leaves a bright trail, that's 400 miles out from the splashdown point (where most of the cameras would be).

So they used long-range land-based aircraft to observe this (KC-135 is more or less a Boeing 707).

[ALOTS is a high-speed film camera capable of 10-80 frames/s](https://www.flyaria.com/airborne-lightweight-optical-tracking-system-aircraft-55-3123.htm). [This source](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/26day9-reentry.html) calls ALOTS a 'still film' camera though. And the way this is worded, I don't think there was an attempt to capture the reentry in motion picture (for Apollo 11).

ALOTS was part of the [Apollo Range Instrumented Aircraft (ARIA) program](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/other_stations/ARIA/index.html).

For Apollo 8 they captured 4 images:

[image]

[image]

the brightest streak at the top is probably the SM breaking up: 
[image]

[image]

That site lists some other ARIA missions in support of Apollo returns, but those seem to have been radio relay missions only.

Several Apollo reentries [were seen by crew and passengers on airliners](http://pages.astronomy.ua.edu/keel/space/apollo.html), and photos were taken. This is one of [Apollo 13](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/msfn_missions/Apollo_13_mission/a13_re-entry-photos.html):

[image]

Comment: The graph shows two slight increases in altitude (after 1st peak g and at the end of the blackout). Is it due to trading kinetic energy (velocity) for potential energy (altitude) (zoom climb)?

Comment: I don't know, I recommend you ask that as a new question.

Comment: [Done](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37253/9072)